# JavaScript Display Image and Text Rather than Alert Message

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm a newbie and starting to learn coding. I have a question regarding the famous "How many fingers am I holding up?" project. So instead of an alert message, I want the actual image of a finger with 1-5 and the message of either it is correct or not.

I think there are jquery codes.. but i don't want to jump to jquery and learn hardcore javascript first. I'm stuck with creating image Arrays and cannot manage to make the image come up.

Here's the code I have:

```
    <body>

    <p>How many fingers am I holding up?</p>

    <p><input type="text" id="guess"> <button id="checkGuess">Guess!</button></p>

    <div id="image"></div>

    <div id="text"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var imgArray = new Array();

        imgArray[1] = new Image();
            imgArray[1].src="images/1.png";

        imgArray[2] = new Image();
            imgArray[2].src="images/2.png";

        imgArray[3] = new Image();
            imgArray[3].src="images/3.png";

        imgArray[4] = new Image();
            imgArray[4].src="images/4.png";

        imgArray[5] = new Image();
            imgArray[5].src="images/5.png";


        document.getElementById("checkGuess").onclick = function() {

            var randomNumber = Math.random();

            randomNumber = randomNumber * 6;

            randomNumber = Math.floor(randomNumber);

            if (document.getElementById("guess").value == randomNumber) {

                doument.getElementById("image").innerHTML = imgArray[num] + alert("Well done! You got it!");

            } else {

                alert("Nope! The number was " + randomNumber);

            }

        }


    </script>



</body>
```

Thanks Guys! Appreciate your help!

Cheers!
Char

Comment: You can try using `modals`. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/6a4p2po4/5/

What I did was to make the imgArray an array of src of images, and updated the img src depending on the result.

I noticed while working you have some typos and unset variables.

For example, "`doument`" is misspelled, and "'`num`'" is not set.

```
doument.getElementById("image").innerHTML = imgArray[num] + alert("Well done! You got it!");
```

It might help to use Chrome or another browser to check the console (F12). It will definitely help you debug.

Using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` will make it show up as a log instead of a pop up window, so you can check the values that you stored on variables, i.e. `console.log(randomNumber);`

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track! Good job so far!

You said

> So **instead** of an alert message, I want the actual image of a finger...

which leads me to think that we *never* want to call `alert()` and instead want to display an image and a message. Assuming I am correct in my supposition, here is some code...

```
<html>
<head>
   <!-- some other stuff... -->

   <!-- CSS is your friend! -->
   <style>
     .hidden {
        display: none;
     }
   </style>
</head>
<body>

<p>How many fingers am I holding up?</p>

<p>
  <input type="text" id="guess"> 
  <button id="checkGuess" onclick="checkGuess()">Guess!</button>
</p>

<div id="image">
  <!-- We can put the images in here then just hide/show them, which is much easier! -->
  <img class="hidden" src="./images/1.png"/>
  <img class="hidden" src="./images/2.png"/>
  <img class="hidden" src="./images/3.png"/>
  <img class="hidden" src="./images/4.png"/>
  <img class="hidden" src="./images/5.png"/>
</div>

<div id="text"></div>

<script>
   function checkGuess(){
     var actualFingerCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
     //the `+` casts the value into a number
     var userGuess = +document.getElementById('guess').value; 
     //get all of our images
     var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
     //hide all of them just to be safe
     images.forEach(function(img){
       img.classList.add('hidden');
     });
     //then show the one we want
     images[actualFingerCount - 1].classList.remove('hidden');

     var textDiv = document.getElementById('text');
     if(actualFingerCount === userGuess) {
       textDiv.innerHTML = 'Yay, you got it!';
     }
     else {
       textDiv.innerHTML = 'Whoops, try again! The number was ' + actualFingerCount + '.';
     }
   } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And there you have it!

Notice that this is a *contrived example*. In the real world, you should never define functions in the global namespace, nor should you rely on elements being in a certain order, like I did with the images. Maybe you can take it and improve it to follow better coding standards!

Comment: HI. Thanks for your help. I tried the code that you gave but how I can make the images not line up? I want it to be one at a time image will appear if the user key in the number.

Comment: @Char They are only "lined up" in the DOM. They're not actually visible to the user. Please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5qmrxp4/) for a demonstration.